Cannot make bell character audible in terminal
How do I get the bell character to play audibly in my tmux session running in xterm?
I am testing if it's audible via sleep 5 && echo -e "\a" then changing focus of windows. I can see the flash but don't hear anything.
I've tried numerous things like these in my ~/.tmux.conf
setw -g monitor-activity on
set -g bell-action any
bind-key -n C-g run-shell "paplay /home/TheUser/beep.ogg"
set -g default-command "paplay /home/TheUser/beep.ogg"
set-hook -g pane-bell "run-shell 'paplay /home/TheUser/beep.ogg'"

Or in my .Xrdb
XTerm*bellIsUrgent:  true
XTerm*visualBell: true
XTerm*audibleBell: true
XTerm*bellVolume: 100
XTerm*bellCommand: /home/TheUser/bin/beep.sh
gnome.terminal.audible-bell: true

xterm version: XTerm(353) 
tmux version: tmux 3.0a

...are your speakers on?

You can see a screenshot of my alsamixer here:https://imgur.com/a/iTAfxYK
I do hear sound from the browser and other programs and the beep script.

I like your terminal theme!

It's Nord theme

For the X11 part you need to have XTerm*visualBell:false or run xterm +vb to disable visible bell at this level. Also check xset q shows the bell is enabled and has a 100% setting (1st value).

This minimal setting worked for me to run a command that plays the bell
when a ^G character is seen by tmux in a background window. In ~/.tmux.conf:
set-option -g monitor-bell on
set-hook -g alert-bell 'run-shell "paplay /home/TheUser/beep.ogg"'

Tested on tmux 3.0a. A printf "\a" to the shell in a non-visible window
causes tmux to run the command paplay and highlihts the window name in the status bar.

Thank you, you are a king! That finally gave me audible bell characters.

Only problem is the fact that I hear the beep whenever I do weird things in the terminal like pressing Alt+UpArrow or pressing PageUp.

Perhaps those keys are generating key sequences that include control-g in the binary? You should probably review some of the other settings you have, like changing to set-option -g bell-action other rather than any, and removing monitor-activity if you only want monitor-bell.
